# How to delete elements from a list that occur before a defined sequence of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

A simple question: I have a list

```
lis = {a,b,c,d,e,f,c,d}
```

I need to delete all the items in the list that occur before the first appearance of "c,d" to make:

```
res = {c,d,e,f,c,d}
```

Drop doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: `lis /. {s___, c, d, e___} :> {c, d, e}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
First@
  SequenceCases[lis, {c, d, __}]

(* Out: {c, d, e, f, c, d} *)
```

Comment: It's slow for a long list, but it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, c, d};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Last @ SequenceSplit[list, x : {c, d, __} :> x]
```

{c, d, e, f, c, d}

Using `Cases` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Cases[list, {___, c, d, e___} :> Splice[{c, d, e}], {0}]
```

{c, d, e, f, c, d}

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = {a, b, e, c, c, d, e, f, c, d};
```

---

Using `Span`:

```
lis[[First @ Select[Flatten@Position[lis, First@{c, d}], 
SameQ[Extract[lis, # + 1], Last@{c, d}] &] ;;]]

(*{c, d, e, f, c, d}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
First@ReplaceList[lis, {b___, c, d, e___} :> {c, d, e}]

(*{c, d, e, f, c, d}*)
```